# How to specify a language across an entire website?

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

For context: I am not a web developer or programmer of any sort and I use a screen-reader.

I am using an accessibility evaluation tool across some sites I'd like to visit, which, however, have some accessibility issues.

From some Googling, I see that it is fairly easy to specify a single webpages language by using `<HTML lang='en'></html>` for example for English.

How easy would it be to implement this across an entire site with hundreds of separate pages? This is a very vague question without linking to the specific website. For example, a car website with a separate page for individual cars with each page missing a specified language. Would it be fairly simple to specify the language across all automatically or would one have to manually copy/paste `<HTML lang='en'></html>` for each page? Or does it heavily depend on how the website was structured HTML-wise? etc.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem. If you have problems accessing a website, then bring up the problem with customer services, not what you think the solution is.

Comment: This is a programming question from someone who wants to know more. Thanks for your time, Quentin.

Comment: No, it isn't a programming question. You aren't trying to write code, you're trying to figure out if you should bother someone else to get them to change code you haven't seen in a way that you don't know with solve some problem you have. Even if you were trying to write code, it would be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I guess you could make a browser extension that checks if its absent and adds it? This isnt really a programming question as he said

Answer (score 4):

You can define the content language sitewide without modifying the HTML using the HTTP header:

```
Content-Language: de-DE
```

This is described in the WCAG :  [Specifying the default language in the HTTP header](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/server-side-script/SVR5.html)

[This header should be used as fallback](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang) by browsers when no `lang` attribute is declared.

> The HTML5 specification says that if there is no `lang` attribute on the `html` tag, and if there is no `meta` element with the `http-equiv` attribute set to `Content-Language`, and if there is only a single language tag in the HTTP header declaration, then a browser may use that information to guess at the default language of the text in the page.

But as noted in the WCAG, this might not be always sufficient:

> Note that the `Content-Language` HTTP header does not serve to identify the language used for processing the content. The content processing language can be identified by means of other techniques, such as the attributes `lang` and `xml:lang` in markup languages.

The technique [Using the language attribute on the HTML element](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H57) must be applied and specifiying the `lang` attribute is something that you won't do an a per-webpage basis, but modifying the site template.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the underlying programming question: Yes, usually changing one file is enough.

You can safely assume that the HTML files that make a website are generated by either a Static Site Generator in advance, or by Content Management System (CMS) on the server when a page is requested.

To generate these files, templates are used. Templates give a common structure and contain variables, which will be replaced by content from the respective page or component.

Usually, there is one main, high-level HTML template, which provides the basic HTML structure with the opening HTML tag `<html>`.

So usually it suffices to change only one file to include the language attribute, by writing `<html lang="en">` in that template, or using a variable for a multi-lingual site `<html lang="{{language}}">` (syntax depends on your generator).